# Basic custom polymer elements aren't showing

Tags: polymer

I've just started learning Polymer and while I can get all the core/paper elements to display properly I can't figure out why my very basic custom element is not showing. It's just two files: "index.html" and "lorem-element.html".

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="lorem-element.html">
</head>
<body>
    <lorem-element></lorem-element>
</body>
</html>
```

lorem-element.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="lorem-element">
  <template>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

I'm not seeing any errors in the javascript console or any 404 errors etc.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. To anyone attempting the same thing here is the answer I was given:

"You need the "noscript" attribute on your polymer-element definition if you're not calling Polymer()"

Which amounts to changing lorem-element.html so it looks like:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="lorem-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```